# Remove the border from the mx MenuBar pop up?

Tags: apache-flex

Is there a way to remove the border from around the MenuBar's pop up?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your css try thise

```
.MenuBar-class {border:none;}
```

Or

```
.MenuBar-class {border:0;}
```